# Installing Ubuntu 16 on My Dual Boot PC [Last Step Not Working]

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

I made the live usb (using Universal USB installer) and now when I say it to boot from the usb and install ubuntu it just restarts winows again. Secure and Fast boots are turned off.

in the grub command prompt:

I get upon `ls`

```
(hd0) (hd0,gpt1) (hd1) (hd1,gpt10) ....  (hd1,gpt1)
```

How could I install ubuntu now. I have backed up both ubuntu and windows data, so I don't care if everything is purged to install ubuntu 16.

Please help. I am badly stuck.

Background:

Dell Inspiron PC with 16 GB Ram. PC can pre-installed Windows 8.1. I installed ubuntu 15.04 as dual boot. Then I upgraded windows to windows 10. And now I want to totally remove both of them to install Ubuntu 16.

What I did:

1. Tried changing the order in boot set-up.
2. Tried using Rufus.
3. Tried all options in the install from usb list (like install ubuntu, boot using ubuntu)

Comment: Ensure you have configured your BIOS to support Legacy or UEFI boot depending of how you have configured the bootable USB

Comment: If pre-installed with Windows 8, then system is newer UEFI system. Generally better to install in UEFI boot mode. Drive is already gpt partitioned, but new install may repartition it. How you boot Ubuntu installer, is then how it installs. You should have an UEFI:flash drive name entry to boot in UEFI mode. Is system Intel or AMD?

Comment: @oldfred its intel core i7. plz help ith the steps. thanks a lot.

Comment: @LorenzoLerate i tried with both. legacy mode -- even the boot order doesnt show usb.

Comment: Try the next: http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media

Comment: Do not know about your Dell, but my older systems did not show boot of USB flash drive, but boot was under hard drive boot options. UEFI should have a UEFI:flash entry if flash drive is bootable. Some have to try different ports, or make sure USB boot is turned on in UEFI and/or Secure Boot is off.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you install the Ubuntu ,1st update it and Install Grab2 customizer and change the order of boot there.
Grab2 customizer must show the windows and ubuntu option in the list.

### sudo apt-get update

### sudo apt-get install grub-customizer

Note: please don't restart Ubuntu on its installation

Comment: i can't even install ubuntu now. that is the problem, how to install despite trying so much.